# How to get device width and height in Xamarin Cocoa apps

Tags: c#, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am developing a cocoa application for OSX in Xamarin. I am facing issues with setting the 100% width of window/form so that it should occupied the full width of the screen. is there any way to detect the screen width so that i can set the width programmatically in c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Screen.Frame` property of the `NSWindow` instance to get the screen dimensions. Set the `NSWindow` instance size with the `SetFrame` method

```
var screenFrame = window.Screen.Frame;
window.SetFrame( new CGRect(0, 0, screenFrame.Width, 400), true, true );
```